# google maps - Как получить событие по нажатию на здание?

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Интегрировал карту в андроид приложение и теперь думаю как выполнять свои действия только тогда когда пользователь нажал на **здание** (выше 5 этажей). Это вообще возможно? Гуглю, гуглю, ничего не нахожу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Это вообще возможно?

А почему нет? Вот отрывок из [документации](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/events):

> Если вам необходимо отреагировать на нажатие пользователем какой-либо
>   точки на карте, используйте OnMapClickListener, который можно
>   установить для карты путем вызова
>   GoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(OnMapClickListener). Когда
>   пользователь нажмет какую-либо точку на карте, вы получите событие
>   onMapClick(LatLng), указывающее место нажатия пользователем. Обратите
>   внимание, если вам необходимы координаты соответствующей точки на
>   экране в пикселях, вы можете получить Projection из карты, что
>   позволит выполнить преобразование между координатами широты/долготы и
>   экранными пикселями.

Для того, чтобы обрабатывалось нажатие именно на здание, можно попробовать сделать следующим образом. Может, это и не лучший вариант, но вот как я это вижу:

при нажатии на какую-либо точку на карте вы получите событие `onMapClick(LatLng`). А далее при его обработке, проверяете, находится ли в фокусе здание, вызвав метод `GoogleMap.getFocusedBuilding()`:

> Чтобы получить здание, которое в настоящий момент находится в фокусе,
>   вызовите GoogleMap.getFocusedBuilding()

Comment: !!!! Воу!!! Спасибо